# JavaFx WebView error on rendering box-shadow

Tags: google-maps, javafx, webview, marker

I'm using the following code to embed a URL into a webview:

```
WebView mapView;
WebEngine engine = mapView.getEngine();
engine.load(MY_URL);
```

The URL contains a Google Map with some markers, and when you hit them, a small dialog appears. This dialog contains a box-shadow, and the problem appears here, because the dialog is not properly rendered.

[The URL rendered in the browser (Google Chrome).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xckfB.png) The dialog is rendered in white, as it should be.

[This one shows the way JavaFx renders the dialogs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtKBh.png)

Is there any other way to embed a map so it appears properly?

Thanks!

PD: I'm using Java 1.8.

Edit: I've also tried changing the UserAgent of the engine using a few ones from chrome and firefox but nothing changes :(

Comment: I think you can't do anything about this. The only thing is wait for Oracle to fix some Style issues in the Webview. Maybe a Java Update will help you.

Comment: We've tried upgrading the Java version from 1.8.0_35 to 1.8.0_65 but it is still not working. We'll continue looking over this issue. Thank you.